# Redirect Messages

Tags: message-coding

The command

`nb = CreateDocument[{}]`

opens an empty notebook. What I want to do is to redirect messages as generated by *Mathematica* so that they appear in this empty notebook. For example, when I enter

`1/0`

I want to see the generated message `Power::infy` in the notebook `nb` instead of in the notebook I am working in or in the Messages Window. Can someone give a hint how that can be done?
Of course, I want to switch off  this behaviour when the notebook `nb` is closed.